# Photoelectric effect vs. electronegativity?

Tags: photons

What connection exists between the photoelectric effect and the electronegativity of a material struck by light?

I'm summing up some stuff in physics, and I got the feeling that the amount of energy (the frequency) in light needed to knock loose electrons might be connected to electronegativity, since that is how hard the atom's "grip" on the electrons is. Since most photoelectric effect descriptions mention metals, I somehow assumed that was because many metals have slightly low electronegativity. But it's just a funny hunch...

Comment: They are completely different. Can you perhaps expand your question to suggest what you think the commonalities might be?

Comment: (EDIT) I wrote something, then thought it fitted in better in the question itself :)

Comment: No, the photoelectric effect is related to the band structure, and specifically to the Fermi level. That is unrelated, or at least not simply related, to electronegativity.